# Visual Studio for Mac: Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core 3.0.5'

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, azure-keyvault

all. When I try to open my project made on Windows system on VS for Mac, I could not build the project. After I searched on the Internet, I found one solution said to update all my Nuget packages; however, I could not update package '`Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core 1.0.0`' to 3.0.5, due to my project targeting `.net framework 4.5`. And I found `System.Web.Entity` under Reference showed '`assembly not found for framework .NET Framework 4.5`'.

Could someone help, many thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last version of the Microsoft Azure Key Vault SDK to support Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 is [2.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core/2.0.4). .NET 4.5 is no longer under support. If you can, you should upgrade to the latest version of .NET Framework or even switch to .NET Core, since no new features are being added to .NET Framework 4.x. .NET Core 3.1 is the latest version of .NET Core, which also supports a lot of platforms while .NET Framework is only supported on Windows.

We also recommend if you can upgrade to switch to Azure.Security.KeyVault packages. The older Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault packages are only getting critical fixes (I'm one of the maintainers). New work is being done in Azure.* packages in general, which are easier to use, faster, and with fewer allocations. See https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/ for details and examples.